# Conditional rendering in Next JS with JWT

Tags: next.js, jwt

I have a component like this :

```
export default function Header () => {

return (

<button>
FIRST BUTTON
</button>

<button>
OTHER BUTTON
</button>
)
}
```

What I need to do is to display the first button if the user is not connected, and replace it by the other button if he is.

I receive the json web token from an other API and I set it in the local storage.

But I don't know what to do after.

I tried to put a ternary expression but it seems that the token is not accessible when the HTML renders so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I set it in the local storage.

You cannot do it with [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) because it's only available on the client-side rendering. With Next.js, you need to keep data for the server-side rendering too.

I'd suggest you should move your json web token to cookies with [`nookies`](https://github.com/maticzav/nookies) that will share values with both client-side and server-side renderings.

And then you can get your token like this

```
export default function Header () => {
   const cookies = nookies.get({}) //get all cookies value
   const { tokenValue } = cookies //`tokenValue` is your cookie name

   return (</>
     {tokenValue ? <button>FIRST BUTTON</button> : <button>OTHER BUTTON</button>}
   </>)
}
```

Beyond that, local storage is not safe from XSS attacks, so we should avoid keeping sensitive data (like tokens) in local storage. You can check [this](https://dev.to/cotter/localstorage-vs-cookies-all-you-need-to-know-about-storing-jwt-tokens-securely-in-the-front-end-15id) out for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
export default function Header() {

    const token = "cookie name";

    return (
        <>
            <button>
                {token ? "FIRST BUTTON" : "OTHER BUTTON"}
            </button>
        </>
    )
}
```